# query specific posts according their custom fields, using sql SELECT

Tags: custom-field, query, sql

My posts have a bunch of custom fields, to help insert and display custom info easily. I am trying to build a search that would select and display posts according values of specific 2 custom fields. The first field "type" is a radio button in my wp-admin, so in database its meta value is always one word. But second field is checkboxes, so in database meta value has several words, and I need to get posts that have the one visitor selects.

What I have so far:

1. Search form, that consists of 2 dropdowns, each for one custom field. I use it one homepage: pastebin.com/zxPuGduW
2. A function in functions.php, to select posts according the values set in dropdowns:
   pastebin.com/Z6D0GM4q
3. A results page to show the posts according selections in the dropdowns form: pastebin.com/KHK0exWn

Comment: What's your question exactly? Why not just use `WP_Query` instead of a raw SQL query?

Comment: Please [edit] relevant code into the question itself. A question should not be dependent upon a third party site.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the question is that it does not work... And I cannot figure it out why. I tried WP_Query way, but was not able to make it search across multiple custom fields at once.

Comment: I was not able to post code here formatted nicely, and I didn't know it is not allowed to use another site...sorry.

Comment: "it does not work" is not a question. Where/how does it fail? You need to do some of the debugging yourself. This site has perfectly adequate code formating-- look for the `{}` button-- though it would be nice if it had line numbers.

Comment: I have tried to find out where it fails with <?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?>  and  <?php $wpdb->print_error(); ?>, but it just prints out my SELECT query then. Changing WP DEBUG to true in wp-config also did not resulted in any errors. And about the {} button - I tried it, but the code was not formatted right in the preview section - should it be that way?

Comment: You are assuming the problem is a `SQL` error. It may not be. `WP_DEBUG` will identify PHP errors/notices but logic mistakes are not PHP errors. Your code can be broken and never through an error. Your code should be formatted in the preview window. You are doing something wrong but I can't tell what. Add your code and try to format it. It can be corrected by other users (nearly everything here is community editable).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [`WP_Query`'s `meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) parameters:

```
$type = 'something';
$programme = 'another';

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => $type,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'programme',
            'value' => $programme,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: OMG, totally! Thank you so much. I am trying that right now. Will update on the results.